# CKEditor Not Getting Space count at the first time

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am not getting the character counter when I press space bar first time in the `ckeditor` Text-Box.

Please, anyone tell me the exact solution for this issue to count the space at the first time.

Comment: Put some code and explain your question more properly.

Comment: without writing anything in the text box which bind with ckeditor when i press sapce bar then i am not getting the character count for that first space.If i write some in that text box and then given the sapce then it is counting that space....